# What is the difference between Reflect.ownKeys(obj) and Object.keys(obj)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Testing them out in a real simple case yields the same output:

```
const obj = {a: 5, b: 5};
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(obj));
console.log(Object.keys(obj));

// Result
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b']
```

When does `Reflect.ownKeys(obj)` produce output different from `Object.keys(obj)`?

Comment: Have you checked the docs?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an `array` of strings, which are the object's own *enumerable* properties.

[`Reflect.ownKeys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys) returns the equivalent* of:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target).
                   concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(target))
```

The `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` method returns an array of all properties ([`enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) **or not**) found directly upon a given object.

The `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` method returns an array of all [`symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) properties found directly upon a given object.

```js
var testObject = {};
Object.defineProperty(testObject, 'myMethod', {
    value: function () {
        alert("Non enumerable property");
    },
    enumerable: false
});

//does not print myMethod since it is defined to be non-enumerable
console.log(Object.keys(testObject));

//prints myMethod irrespective of it being enumerable or not.
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(testObject));
```

> (*) "`Reflect.ownKeys(target)` is usually equivalent to `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(target))`. **However**, if the object has a custom `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` method (such as through a proxy's ownKeys handler), the order of the keys may be different." [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys#description)

Comment: Is there a use for this?

Comment: It's also an important distinction between keys & symbols which may or may not need to be enumerated as two distinct things

Answer (score 16):

First, an example ([ES6Fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iijyw482/)):

```
// getFoo is property which isn't enumerable
var my_obj = Object.create({}, { getFoo: { value: function() { return this.foo; } } });
my_obj.foo = 1;

console.log(Object.keys(my_obj)); // console ['foo']
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(my_obj)); // console ['getFoo', 'foo']
```

Here, `Reflect.ownKeys()` returns an array of the target object's own property keys. Namely, an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon the given object concatenated with an array of all [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) properties found directly upon the given object.

`Object.keys()` will only return the enumerable properties.

Enumerable properties are those that can be enumerated by a [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), with the exception of properties inherited through the prototype chain.  See [the MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) for more details.

**Summary:**

[Reflect.ownKeys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys) is the equivalent of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(target))` which will return both enumerable and non-enumerable properties

whereas

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns enumerable properties but does not return non-enumerable properties (which is a characteristic of [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what the other answers have already mentioned, `Reflect.ownKeys` is also *guaranteed* by the specification to return keys (and symbols) in the following order:

- Integer numeric keys, in ascending order (0, 1, 2)
- String keys, **in the order they were inserted onto the object**
- Symbol keys

This order is required by the internal  [`[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) method which is invoked by [`Reflect.ownKeys`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-reflect.ownkeys).

In contrast, `Object.keys` calls [`EnumerableOwnPropertyNames`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-enumerableownpropertynames), which requires:

> 5. Order the elements of `properties` so they are in the same relative order as would be produced by the Iterator that would be returned if the [EnumerateObjectProperties](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties) internal method were invoked with O.

Where [EnumerateObjectProperties](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties) explicitly **does not specify** any order in which the properties are returned:

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified

So, if you want to be *absolutely certain* that, while iterating over object properties, you iterate in insertion order for non-numeric keys, make sure to use `Reflect.ownKeys` (or [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object.getownpropertynames), which also invokes `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`).

(All that said, while `Object.keys`, its variants, `for..in` loops, and `JSON.stringify` all officially iterate in an unspecified, implementation-dependant order, environments generally iterate in the same predictable order as `Reflect.ownKeys` anyway, luckily)

Answer (score 6):

- `Object.keys` returns only enumerable string keys; `Reflect.ownKeys` returns both string and symbol keys regardless of their enumerability. Both operate on own properties only.
- `Object.keys` returns an empty array if the argument is not an object and not `null` or `undefined` (e.g. `Object.keys(1)`), whereas `Reflect.ownKeys` throws a `TypeError`.
- `Reflect.ownKeys` was introduced with ES6 and is not supported in older JavaScript engines.

Comment: [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/1048572). Actually, *only* `Reflect.ownKeys` will give a deterministic key order, `Object.keys` might do anything else.

Comment: @Bergi I believe you're right about that. Was indeed misreading point 6 in 7.3.21 EnumerableOwnNames (O). Thanks for pointing out.