# See all keys of a JS object, even those defined by getters

Tags: javascript

I would like to `JSON.stringify` all properties of an object, including those defined via getters. However, when I call `JSON.stringify` on an object, properties defined via getters are omitted:

```
> const obj = {key: 'val'}
undefined

> JSON.stringify(obj)
'{"key":"val"}'

> Object.defineProperty(obj, 'getter', {get: () => 'from getter'})
{ key: 'val' }

> obj.getter
'from getter'

> JSON.stringify(obj)
'{"key":"val"}'
```

I was hoping to see:

```
> JSON.stringify(obj)
'{"key":"val", "getter": "from getter"}'
```

Is this possible? `Object.keys` isn't detecting the getters either:

```
> Object.keys(obj)
[ 'key' ]
```

Can you query for getter keys? Or do you have to know their names ahead of time?

Comment: The fact that it is a getter is irrelevant; the problem is that it's non-enumerable. (`Object.defineProperty` uses a default `enumerable: false`.) You want to enumerate non-enumerable properties (which can be done, but that's the description of your issue).

Comment: perhaps make the property enumerable? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute

Comment: @apsillers: Make it an answer :)

Comment: As a counter example to your getter theory, try `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'nogetter', {value: 'not a getter'})`

Comment: While @apsillers answered the main question, you can query for getter keys by using [`Reflect.ownKeys()`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2&code=const%20obj%20%3D%20%7Bkey%3A%20'val'%7D%3B%0AObject.defineProperty(obj%2C%20'getter'%2C%20%7Bget%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'from%20getter'%7D)%0A%0Aconsole.log(Reflect.ownKeys(obj))%3B) the same way you would use `Object.keys()`, except Reflect doesn't care if the property is enumerable or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify` only includes enumerable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733878/why-does-json-stringify-not-serialize-non-enumerable-properties) in its output.

When `enumerable` is not specified on the property descriptor passed into [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description), it defaults to `enumerable: false`. Thus, any property definition done by `Object.defineProperty` (with a getter or not) will be non-enumerable unless you explicitly specify `enumerable: true`.

You can get all the properties that exist on an object (N.B: not inherited properties) with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` or (in ES2015+) `Reflect.ownKeys`. (The only difference between these is that [`Reflect.ownKeys` also includes properties defined by a `Symbol` key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34449216/710446).) It is not possible to make `JSON.stringify` include non-enumerable properties; you must instead make the property enumerable.